# How to get all Pod's IP on a kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

i should get the IP of all the Pods of the kubernetes.

I tried to try it with the provided java API, but I get a java.lang.NullPointerException.

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/

```
ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

        CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
        V1PodList list = api.listPodForAllNamespaces(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        for (V1Pod item : list.getItems()) {
            System.out.println(item.getMetadata().getName());
        }
```

Is there any way to get the IP of all running pods in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ApiClient client = Config. fromConfig(kubeconfigFilePath)` instead of using `ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();`

In general `kubeConfigFilePath` is `$HOME/.kube/config`.